# Parent Child Relationship provided no Parent to Child relation

Tags: java, data-structures, children, flags

I have to segregate all parents and child in list with a flag (say, `isParent`) attached to my `Object` which says whether given `Object` is a parent or a child.
`MyObject` structure is like below :

```
class MyObject {
  MyObjectId iD; //MyObject Id
  MyObjectId parentId; //ParentId of the Object, When an Object is root Object then the parentId will be null
}
```

I have one transaction which takes `MyObjectId` and returns me the corresponding `MyObject` which is like below:

```
public MyObject getMyObject(MyObjectId myObjectId)
```

I am provided with a list which contains many parent `Object` which has children which are parent to other sub-children and there are also `MyObject` which don't have children.

I need to segregate all the parent `Object` and child `Object`s in a Data structure and assign them a flag which says whether they are child or parent.

Comment: please put your code in a code block; highlight your code and click `shift+k` on windows or `command+k` on mac

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You start by explaining that child objects can also be parents of other sub-children. And then you say that you must assign them a flag that says if they're parents or children. So, what if they are both? And moreover: what have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: for your 'segregation' why dont you just check if the object `isOfType` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

What your describing is a tree like structure:

- Parent (root)

  - Child
  - Child & Parent

    - Child

So it looks like you're going to want an isParent flag and an isChild flag.  You'll know that a currentNode is a Child node if its parentId is not null, and you'll know if this same currentNode is a parent because another node will have its parentId be equal to the currentNode's iD.